# How to skip the extra newline while printing lines read from a file?

Tags: python

I am reading input for my python program from stdin (I have assigned a file object to stdin). The number of lines of input is not known beforehand. Sometimes the program might get 1 line, 100 lines or even no lines at all.

```
import sys
sys.stdin  = open ("Input.txt")
sys.stdout = open ("Output.txt", "w")

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print line

main()
```

This is the closest to my requirement. But this has a problem. If the input is

```
3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

it prints

```
3

7 4

2 4 6

8 5 9 3
```

It prints an extra newline after every line. How do I fix this program or whats the best way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** Here is the sample run http://ideone.com/8GD0W7

---

**EDIT2:** Thanks for the Answer. I got to know the mistake.

```
import sys
sys.stdin  = open ("Input.txt")
sys.stdout = open ("Output.txt", "w")

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        for data in line.split():
            print data,
        print ""

main()
```

Changed the program like this and it works as expected. :)

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know how this post can be improved.

Comment: I would say two possible reasons for a downvote: 1. Title is misleading, it's not about handling of EOF at all; 2. in EDIT2, why do you even need the split? you should either print `line,` or `line.strip()`, but your code also squeezes spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the python `print` statement adds a newline, but the original line already had a newline on it.  You can suppress it by adding a comma at the end:

```
print line , #<--- trailing comma
```

For python3, (where `print` becomes a function), this looks like:

```
print(line,end='') #rather than the default `print(line,end='\n')`.
```

---

Alternatively, you can strip the newline off the end of the line before you print it:

```
print line.rstrip('\n') # There are other options, e.g. line[:-1], ...
```

but I don't think that's nearly as pretty.

Comment: Or, use sys.stout.write() instead of print, when you care about appearance.